# Windows phone 8.1 Handling App from Close button in the page

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In my windows phone app, i have to delete some files when user navigates away from a page.
I have handled this on OnBackKeyPress event. This works perfectly fine.
The issue is newer updates of windows phone 8 and windows phone 8.1 also have close button on the top right corner. I have not found a way to handle this event. 
Could anyone please let me know how can i handle this event and delete the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using OnBackKeyPress, you should use OnNavigatedFrom. This event is triggered whenever the user leaves the page, no matter how.

---

If you need to handle only the specific case when the app is suspended/terminated, you can subscribe to the `Deactivated` and `Closing` events on the PhoneApplicationService.

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Deactivated += yourHandler;
```

Note that is the your event handler is a non-static method declared in your page, then you must make sure to unsubscribe the event when leaving the page, to avoid a memory leak. To know when to unsubscribe, you can stick to your OnBackKeyPress logic.

Comment: Say for example, i have MainPage, Page1. I open Page1 from MainPage. I delete the files when i navigate back to MainPage from Page1. There is also this case where i open Page2 from Page1 and in this case i don't want to delete the file. That is why i am not handling deletion of files in OnNavigatedFrom of Page but in BackKeyPress. Can u suggest me any other alternative.

Comment: I tried what you said. But the problem remains. yourHandler gets called when i long press the back key. At this moment, i do not know if my app is gonna be closed or sent to background.  If sent to background than i cannot delete the file because when the app is resumed it will not find the files. Some if could tap the close button. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Even Microsoft.Phone.Shell.PhoneApplicationService.Current.Closing eventhandler does not get called when i long press the back key and tap on close button to close the app. I tried this in debug mode. I should try this in release mode once how it behaves.

Comment: @ashok Unfortunately it's how Windows Phone works. When your app gets deactivated, the system is allowed to kill it without any kind of notification. That's not a situation you can handle. In the worst case, when the Closing event isn't called, delete the files at next app startup